# Positioning the bottom of a div with position:fixed

Tags: css

I have a div with dynamic content that I'd like to position 500px from top of the viewport. Using

```
position:fixed;
top:500px
```

positions the TOP of the div, but how can I achieve to position the BOTTOM of the div 500 px from top?

Here is an example: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/us6op.gif]

P.S.:

```
position:fixed; 
bottom: 12345px
```

is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it by putting the content into another div and then positioning it absolutely to the bottom of the fixed div like so: http://jsfiddle.net/JDq9C/

**html**

```
<div id="fixed">
    <div id="dynamic">
        blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#fixed {position:fixed; top:500px; left:0;}
#dynamic {position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```